# Django - resource was not found on this server on production

Tags: django, nginx, django-import-export

I am trying to access these files used from the `django-import-export-celery` module:
[image]

I am able to see my view on local:

[image]

But its not showing on my production server:

[image]

This is my `urlpattern`:

```
urlpatterns = static(
    settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
) + [

    # favicon
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('img/Dalmore-Group-16-16.png'))),
    # debug
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),

]
```

And my `settings.py` has:

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**UPDATE**:

I am receiving this error on my logs:

```
tail /var/log/gunicorn.err.log
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /media/django-import-export-celery-import-change-summaries/new1_1_1hRlmBz_ubIptVv_St8xqbE_1_z2_PGH9e4O.html
```

Even though it's present:

```
ls -A media/django-import-export-celery-import-change-summaries/
new1_1_1hRlmBz_ubIptVv_St8xqbE_1_z2_PGH9e4O.html
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this:

```
location /media/ { 
    root /home/ubuntu/dalmoreportal;
}
```

in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/django.conf`